# Python recursive function for treant js

Tags: python, recursion, tree, recursive-datastructures

I am trying to generate a tree for the treant js library, however, looking at the JSON format that they expect is putting me in some difficulties in generating the tree correctly as they want it.

Currently, here's what I've done:

This is the output the [library](https://fperucic.github.io/treant-js/) wants:

```
"""
output = {
    metric_1 : {
        name : 'metric 1', desc: 'desc', contact: 'form * x - y'
    },
    children: [{
        metric_2 : {
            name : 'metric 2', desc: 'desc', contact: 'form * x - y'
        },
    },
    // Metric 2 has children, add the children attribute on the same level as metric_2
    children : [{
        ...
    }],
    {
        metric_3 : {
            name : 'metric 3', desc: 'desc', contact: 'form * x - y'
        }
    },
    ]
}
"""
```

This is my attempt:

```
def get_records():
    # ID, Tree ID, Metric Name, Metric Description, Metric Formula, Parent, ReferenceID
    records = (('1', '1', 'metric 1', 'desc', 'form * x  - y', '', 'metric_1'),
    ('2', '1', 'metric 2', 'desc', 'form * x  - y', 'metric_1', 'metric_2'),
    ('3', '1', 'metric 3', 'desc', 'form * x  - y', 'metric_1', 'metric_3'),
    ('4', '1', 'metric 4', 'desc', 'form * x  - y', 'metric_2', 'metric_4'),
    ('5', '1', 'metric 5', 'desc', 'form * x  - y', 'metric_2', 'metric_5'))
    return records


def generate_output(record, output={}):
    def generate(record):
        #print(output)
        # rowno, tree_id, metric_name, metric_desc, metric_form, parent, refid
        try:
            output['children'].append({record[6] : {'name': record[2], 'title': record[3], 'contact': record[4]}})
        except KeyError:
            output[record[6]] = {'name': record[2], 'title': record[3], 'contact': record[4]}
        if children:=find_children(record[6]):
            try:
                if output['children']:
                    pass
            except KeyError:
                output['children'] = []
            for child in children:
                generate(child)
    generate(record)
    return output

def find_children(argrefid):
    records = get_records()
    output = []
    for record in records:
        if record[5] == argrefid:
            output.append(record)
    return output

if __name__ == '__main__':
    for record in get_records():
        print(generate_output(record))
        break 
    # Need to only pass the first element to recursively create the tree
```

The first cycle works as intended, however I find it difficult to create a `children` array recursively on the same level of the metric that they request, this is what my program outputs:

```
{'metric_1': {'name': 'metric 1', 'title': 'desc', 'contact': 'form * x  - y'}, 'children': [{'metric_2': {'name': 'metric 2', 'title': 'desc', 'contact': 'form * x  - y'}}, {'metric_4': {'name': 'metric 4', 'title': 'desc', 'contact': 'form * x  - y'}}, {'metric_5': {'name': 'metric 5', 'title': 'desc', 'contact': 'form * x  - y'}}, {'metric_3': {'name': 'metric 3', 'title': 'desc', 'contact': 'form * x  - y'}}]}
```

However I would like, as I said to have metric 4 and metric 5 as children of its parent, metric2.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would not solve this recursively, but iteratively:

1. Build items from each record in a step
2. Link them to their respective parents in a second step

Sample

```
import json

def get_records():
           # ID, TreeID, MetricName, MetricDescription, MetricFormula, Parent, ReferenceID
    return (('1', '1', 'metric 1', 'desc', 'form * x  - y', '', 'metric_1'),
            ('2', '1', 'metric 2', 'desc', 'form * x  - y', 'metric_1', 'metric_2'),
            ('3', '1', 'metric 3', 'desc', 'form * x  - y', 'metric_1', 'metric_3'),
            ('4', '1', 'metric 4', 'desc', 'form * x  - y', 'metric_2', 'metric_4'),
            ('5', '1', 'metric 5', 'desc', 'form * x  - y', 'metric_2', 'metric_5'))

records = get_records()

# 1. build all entries and index them by their referene ID
entry_by_ref = {}
for record in records:
    entry_by_ref[record[6]] = {
        'name': record[2],
        'title': record[3],
        'contact': record[4],
    }

# 2. find root node and link all others into a tree
root = None
for record in records:
    entry = entry_by_ref.get(record[6])
    parent = entry_by_ref.get(record[5])
    if record[5] == '':
        root = entry
    elif parent is not None:
        if 'children' not in parent:
            parent['children'] = []
        parent['children'].append(entry)

print(json.dumps(root, indent=2))
```

the above outputs:

```
{
  "name": "metric 1",
  "title": "desc",
  "contact": "form * x  - y",
  "children": [
    {
      "name": "metric 2",
      "title": "desc",
      "contact": "form * x  - y",
      "children": [
        {
          "name": "metric 4",
          "title": "desc",
          "contact": "form * x  - y"
        },
        {
          "name": "metric 5",
          "title": "desc",
          "contact": "form * x  - y"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "metric 3",
      "title": "desc",
      "contact": "form * x  - y"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your insights, this solves perfectly the problem and it's a lot easier to work with and understand compared to what I was trying to do.